# NSString to NSDate conversion problem: always the same date!

Tags: objective-c, datetime

Here is my class method for parsing a `NSString` to a `NSDate` object. Here is the code:

```
+ (NSDate *) stringToDate:(NSString *) string {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.AAA Z"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    NSLog(@"stringToDate(\"%@\") = '%@'", string, date);
    [dateFormatter release];
    return date;
}
```

and running it i get the following output:

```
stringToDate("2011-07-07 16:26:07.000 +0200") = '2011-07-06 22:00:00 +0000'
stringToDate("2011-07-07 16:26:17.000 +0200") = '2011-07-06 22:00:00 +0000'
```

... the same output! Can you help me?

Comment: ... and that's what happens for other conversions:

stringToDate("2011-06-24 08:00:00.000 +0200") = '2011-06-23 22:00:00 +0000'

stringToDate("2011-07-24 08:00:00.000 +0200") = '2011-07-23 22:00:00 +0000'

Comment: Not sure I understood your problem with this "stringToDate("2011-06-24 08:00:00.000 +0200") = '2011-06-23 22:00:00 +0000' stringToDate("2011-07-24 08:00:00.000 +0200") = '2011-07-23 22:00:00 +0000' "

But if your issue was that regardless what input string you passed, the return date strings are the same...  if this is the case, check to make sure the strings you are passing are  different.

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
NSLog(@"stringToDate(\"%@\") = '%@'", string, 
       [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Otherwise, `NSLog` calls the `description` method of your `date` object. Here is what the documentation says about this method:

> **description**
>
> Returns a string representation of the receiver.
>
> -(NSString *)description
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A string representation of the receiver in the international format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM, where ±HHMM represents the time zone offset in hours and minutes from GMT (for example, “2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600”).

As you can see, the format is not exactly the same as the one you use.

**edit**

Try changing the dateFormat parameter of your `dateFormatter` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` and use `[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]` to display your date.

Comment: Actually, that is my goal. I'm expecting something like:
stringToDate("2011-07-07 17:14:40.000 +0200") = '2011-07-07 17:14:40 +0200'

Comment: I think Tejesh and I are both right: the dateFormatter you use is adjusting the time zone and the international format used by the `description` method - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM` is not gonna give you what you excpect. See my edit.

Comment: I left the `description` method be invoked on `date` object. I just changed the format to **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000 Z"** (000 instead of AAA) and **it works**! For my goal it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, your problem is that the two dates are not exactly the same.

If this is the problem, the line

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

is responsible for it. It is converting the given time object to GMT+00 time zone.